# bootstrap textarea with panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, textarea, panel

I am having issues making the text area fill the width of the panel any ideas??

My code is below

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div id="div_EssentialInformation" class="panel-heading">Essential information</div>
    <div id="content" style="display:none;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a id="btn_edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                <a id="btn_save" class="btn btn-danger" style="display:none">Save</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have a script that toggles the display of the content div, below is the js script

```
$("#div_EssentialInformation").click(function () {
        $("#content").slideToggle(500);
    })
```

I am getting this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
textarea {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry no that is not the problem i should have stated i have a piece of JS code that toggle the display. the issue is that the text area does not span the whole width of the panel

Comment: i have edited the original question with this js code

Comment: Sorry this still does not span the whole panel body

Comment: why do you mean when you say span? do you want the sides of the textarea touching the sides of the screen?

Comment: i have just added an image, what I am after is the textbox to stretch all the way to the right with the same margin as the left hand side

Comment: are you linking both bootstrap css and js along with jquery because when I check for problem I see nothing wrong on my computer

Comment: I will play dumb here and ask what you mean by linking bostrap css and js along with jquery

Comment: I updated the answer to show you what I mean. linking the bootstrap framework and jquery.

Comment: When I add those lines into the project I get no panel displayed at all, so I am using ASP.net MVC and I am loding the bootstrap css and Jquery and bootstrap scripts

Comment: Oh ok that makes since. I just edited the answer. Try and see if this works.

Comment: ok fixed it.  And thankyou you definately put me onto the right track.  asp.net comes with a site.css file which forces all inputs to be 280px wide (why they do this I dont know) so i changed that and all working now!   Thanks mate

Comment: No problem. I worked with ASP.NET MVC before and it does have quirks like that. My final answer would have worked then since you are declaring it as important, it would have override the set width for the textarea assigned by site.css file. This was a fun journey. If you ever want to collaborate on a project please let me know.

Comment: Would always be interested in collaborating, not only do I have a bunch of crazy work people want me to do I also have some quite cools ideas too :)

Comment: Awesome, once you you want to collaborate please contact me. Here is my website: austinjorgensen.net , Please send me an email using my email form on my website. I would leave my email here but I do not want spam.